# Quickly write a unitary transformation connecting two arbitrary states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, unitarity

This is for an introductory QM course. Say, I have pure states $\vert\alpha\rangle$ and $\vert\beta\rangle$. I would like to find a unitary operator that takes me from one to the other. What is the obvious way to do this? I also realize that the constraints are not fully specified but that's fine.

If I try $U = \vert\beta\rangle\langle\alpha\vert$, this seems to do the job but is not unitary. Other approaches seem quite messy e.g. the answer at [Unitary transformation from pure unentangled state to pure entangled state](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402081/unitary-transformation-from-pure-unentangled-state-to-pure-entangled-state) (nothing to do with entanglement).

What is an efficient way to find the requisite $U$ given the states in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $\{ | \phi_i \rangle \}$ is a orthonormal basis, and $\{ | \psi_i \rangle \}$ another, then
$$ U: | \phi_i \rangle \mapsto | \psi_i \rangle $$
(or, formally, $U = \sum_i | \psi_i \rangle\!\langle \phi_i |$) is unitary.

So, you just have to find such orthonormal bases with $|\alpha\rangle = |\phi_0\rangle$, $|\beta\rangle = |\psi_0\rangle$. Than can be done e.g. using the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Answer (score 1):

To simplify notation and make manipulations easier, let's focus on a finite Hilbert space $H$ that is spanned by a complete orthonormal set {${|\phi_1 \rangle, |\phi_2 \rangle,...,|\phi_N \rangle }$}. Let's look for a unitary operator $U$ that switches two states, and we can take them to be $|\phi_1 \rangle$ and $|\phi_2 \rangle$ without loss of generality. Then:
$$U|\phi_1 \rangle=|\phi_2 \rangle$$
$$U|\phi_2 \rangle=|\phi_1 \rangle$$
$$\langle\Psi |U^{\dagger}U|\Psi \rangle=\langle\Psi |\Psi \rangle$$

By simple analogy to how this would be done in $\mathbb{R}^N$, we can choose:

$$U=|\phi_1 \rangle \langle\phi_2 |+|\phi_2 \rangle \langle\phi_1 |+\sum_{i=3}^N|\phi_i \rangle \langle\phi_i |$$

Using this expression for $U$ in the first three equations, and using the stated facts that the states are orthonormal, i.e. $\langle\phi_i |\phi_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$, and that this basis set is complete, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^N|\phi_i \rangle \langle\phi_i |=I$, it is easy to show that this is the correct expression for $U$.